# What is the convergence order of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

What is the convergence order of the following iterative series:
$x_{n+1}=e^{x_n*x_{n-1}}-1 $ when we're given that it converges to c=0.

With the definition of $\epsilon_n=x_n-c$, it was a little complicated ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the sequence converges, it converges to a fixed point of $g(x)= e^{x^2}-1$, so it will either diverge, converge to $z_1=0$ or converge to $z_2\approx 0.746882$. The second fixed point is unstable and only by shear luck (for instance starting right on the fixed point) will you obtain convergence. So, in your case you should just use $c=0$ in the definition of $e_n$, as it is proposed.

Comment: Yeah i used 0 in epsilon ...but couldn't complete after substituting ,it was complicated to me..

Comment: then can u tell me what the convergence's order will be?

Comment: @user726608 If we had the usual (one step) fixed poin $x_{n+1}=e^{x_n^2}-1$, since $g'(0)=0$ and $g''(0) \ne 0$, the order of convergence would be $2$. I'm not sure the the order will be the same, but this is something that you can check numerically.